# Why is this website using html5 pushstate not seo friendly?

Tags: javascript, html, seo, history.js

I just built this website using the html5 history api and 'pushstate' using the history.js library.

http://renovari.co.uk

I submitted it to be indexed by google, but after I check the results for the website in google, I can see that the text is not being crawled.

I've seen many examples on the internet where this is supposed to work...

What's the problem?

Comment: Have'nt studied the code, but usually the problem is that you should build your site with real links to real pages, and **then** use HTML5 history and ajax to load stuff dynamically, that way the links and pages can be crawled and it works in older browsers as well.

Comment: Not according to this website: http://html5.gingerhost.com/
"This site uses HTML5 wizrdry to load the 'actual content' asynchronusly to the rest of the code: this makes it faster for users, but it's still totally indexable by search engines." Also cited here: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what adeneo said. http://html5.gingerhost.com/seattle is a real page you see, a real page with real links. Then, HTML5/JS is used to give the illusion that it isn't. You still need real pages.

Comment: Ok my apologies, you are both correct. In that demo he loads his content from a file called content.php, but when javascript is disabled is the content loaded from separate pages (i.e /seattle.html and made into a friendly url with htaccess) or is the server doing something else to split content.php into multiple pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in visitors with no JS, like the google bot.

You depend on JavaScript to load the page content, and therefore it is not indexed.

Try to disable JavaScript in your browser and you can see this.

To fix this there are many ways to go ahead, but basically you want to serve the first page-load as a page with content always, and from then on load new content in via JS.

If you use hashbangs you can do a thing like [this](http://www.seoinc.com/seo-blog/making-ajax-application-crawlable-for-search-engine-optimization/). But you will find a lot of tropics around the web if you make a search.

Wikipedia also have [this great article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) about it.

Comment: Thanks Allan, this answered the question. If you visit the website now you will see it's now SEO friendly. Thanks!